# Предотвращения обновления сайта через форму

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, функции, form, frontend

Есть сайт на который можно загружать картинку через простенькую форму [image: Форма]

Однако на данный момент загрузка невозможна, т.к. форма перегружает сайт и удаляет внесенную "карточку товара".

Как убрать обновление сайта при нажатии `submit-button`?

```js
const productImage = document.getElementById("product-image");
const productPrice = document.getElementById("product-price");
const productName = document.getElementById("product-name");
const addButton = document.getElementById("submit-button");
// const productGallery = document.getElementById("product-gallery");

addButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  let newproductCard = document.createElement('div')
  newproductCard.classList.add('product-card')

  let newproductImage = document.createElement('img')
  newproductImage.classList.add('product-image')
  //пока не работает//

  let price = parseInt(document.getElementById("product-price").value);
  let newproductPrice = document.createElement('div')
  let newproductPriceText = document.createTextNode(`${price}`)
  newproductPrice.appendChild(newproductPriceText)
  productPrice.classList.add('product-price')

  let name = document.getElementById("product-price").value;
  let newproductName = document.createElement('div')
  let newproductNameText = document.createTextNode(`${name}`)
  newproductName.classList.add('product-name')
  newproductName.appendChild(newproductNameText)

  newproductCard.appendChild(newproductImage)
  newproductCard.appendChild(newproductPrice)
  newproductCard.appendChild(newproductName)
  productGallery.appendChild(newproductCard)

})
```

```html
<main>
  <form class="form-field">
    <input type="file" id="product-image" placeholder="Картинка товара" accept="image/*" />
    <input type="text" id="product-price" placeholder="Цена товара" />
    <input type="text" id="product-name" placeholder="Название товара" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Добавить" />
  </form>
  <div class="product-gallery">
    <div class="product-card">
      <img class="product-image" src="https://picsum.photos/300?random=1" />
      <div class="product-price">300 Руб.</div>
      <div class="product-name">Ну товар какой-то</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: зачем несколько раз `getElementById("product-price")`?

Answer (score 1):

Самое просто, вместо типа инпута `submit` сделать тип инпута `button`, т.к. если не нужно сабмитить форму, то зачем кнопка сабмита?

Comment: Так бы и сделал, но в задании нужна именно форма, а слово препода - закон

Comment: @bruh ты не понял. форма остаётся. просто тип кнопки, на которую нажали будет не сабмит, а просто кнопка

Answer (score 0):

```
yourFormElement.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
});
```

Либо там где отлавливаете клип по кнопке, в начале функции добавьте `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: А как тогда будет происходить сабмит данных? (Я знаю что это можно сделать через JS, но на данном примере такой реализации нет)

Comment: @ΝNL993 например через ```fetch``` https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch

Comment: Я знаю `fetch`... Но в коде который находится в вашем ответе нет такой реализации.

Comment: @ΝNL993 моя реализация - ответ на вопрос. А отправка/получение данных это уже другой вопрос.  Дальше, при необходимости, fetch можно прописать где нужно. Например привязать обработчик по клику на кнопку, и в нём выполнять отправку/получение данных. Или по какому-либо другому событию

Comment: Справедливо. А зачем на какое-то другое событие? Легче же просто клик.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Всё зависит от задачи. Можно при нажатии Enter, можно при вставке в поле (например форма кода подтверждения, если код правильный, он автоматически подхватывается, когда пользователь вставляет его в поле) и тд и тп